# Is there a way to speed up the blue questionmark encounters?

Tags: days-gone

Once in a while blue question marks appear on the minimap.
Sometimes they have blue circles on the world map<sup>1</sup> but sometimes there is no other clue except for the direction at all. and since the marker disappears within a few seconds, I very often even just have to estimate the range, making me spend multiple minutes of game time spending for figuring, in which area an event could have taken place.

Then, in the lucky case, my chase wasn't for nothing, I end up in an area, finding a trail in survival vision. These trails not rarely leading to nothing<sup>2</sup>. I mean I expect there should be additional tracks to follow, but sometimes I can hardly if at all find them. Making me in the end having invested like 20~30 minutes of playtime for finding (if lucky) something like an ammo box in the end. So is there a way, like a specific pattern or something I am not aware yet to look out for, to finish these encounters within a few minutes<sup>3</sup>?

---

<sup>1</sup> I am not 100% sure if these 2 things are connected, since its irregular

<sup>2</sup> Well at least I find nothing.

<sup>3</sup> As that's the maximum amount of time I'd be willing to spent on a track down that *might* reward me with an survivor but most often with nothing but crap my inventory is filled with already anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Blue question marks act more like a "hint direction" than anything else. From [gamepressure.com](https://guides.gamepressure.com/days-gone/guide.asp?ID=49724):

> The appearance of a blue question mark on the mini-map does not mean additional hassle. The questionnaire also does not symbolize something important. Question marks are instructed to direct you to the locations of minor investigations. Ignoring them will not result in any bad consequences. You can check out this places if you are looking for extra adventures.

A good way to track them down quicker is to [scan with **R3**](https://www.reddit.com/r/DaysGone/comments/bia3az/blue_question_marks_disappear_way_too_fast/). You should be looking for a trail to follow. Sometimes these trails are marked with **blood**, **tracks**, or other **signs of struggle**. Also, the controller should [vibrate](https://guides.gamepressure.com/days-gone/guide.asp?ID=49724) when you get close to the minor objective, and as you walk over the trail. If you use all the tricks available to you, you shouldn't have difficulty completing these objectives, but just remember that all blue question mark objectives **can be safely ignored.**

[image: what a blue question mark looks like]

Comment: Funny enough, yesterday I made it in time to the origin of one of the marks. I was ltierally standing on it and nothing was around at all. Also all the methods you mentioned I was already using, So I take your answer as "No, there are no additional things to speed the process up."?

Comment: Sorry, those are the only mechanics in the game that are there to speed up the process. If you're looking for additional strategy, sometimes I follow the blue question mark.

Comment: Yeah, the blue question marks are frustrating. They usually indicate an ambush camp or someone to rescue from a car being attacked by freakers. They do seem to be timed, in that the optional objective disappears if you don't get there quickly. And yet, like you, I've rushed there only to find nothing at all.